# How to automate Exe software like automate Chrome in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, exe

How can I automate clicking on non-browser interactive interfaces (eg. Exe software) without image recognization? (For example, Microsoft's onenote, or some niche software)

I want to learn related technologies, but I don't know which direction I should go, I hope someone can give me some guidance.

*(Now I can only use Python's image recognition and click technology for these non-browser software, but this efficiency is very low. I hope that I can skip the image recognition & click directly, and can directly manipulate the underlying data processing like manipulating HTTP request or CSS selenium )*

Comment: [Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/)

Comment: @Burning Alcohol  No, pyautogui is just what I used, but it is unstable!!  I need click a button without 'click', but just manipulate the ground code, Click an HTML button compared with manipulating javascript of HTML, the latter is clearly better

Comment: If you don't mind going low-level, you could try using the win32api wrappers for python. The WINAPI has functions that let you enumerate windows/window elements, and get handles to them, which should let you automate your interaction with them.

Answer (score 0):

Free tools are - Autoit, AutoHotkey, Winium etc
Free tools cannot recognise most of the windows so might need to consider paid tools.

Paid options are - Testcomplete, UFT(QTP),  Automation anywhere, UI path, Ranorex, Squish

My personal recommendation is Test complete. Because I never found a blocker in windows automation, user friendly and economically viable.